# Desktop level editor for a game

Tags: java, android

(Edited for better clarity)
I am making a level-based puzzle game in Android Studio.

Question:
I want to write a level editor to run on my pc where I select and place screen elements (blocks, enemies, player start point etc), can then save this in a file that is readable and loadable by my Android game app.

Further Context:
My Android Project already has classes for these screen elements, so I would think that I use the same classes to display and put relations between these elements so that I can just save the container object to a file and then later read that file to get the properly structured object (a grid with blocks, enemy and player position and orientation defined within this grid). I would like to stay within the bounds of free android resources, and not use proprietary solutions like Unity.

What I have tried so far:
I have tried making a swing dependent JFrame class in my Android Studio project, which did not work. I found out on stackoverflow that AS doesn't allow swing to be imported.

I then thought of making a project in Eclipse and importing the game classes I would use in the editor from my Android project. I could not figure out how to do this. A solution to somewhat related questions seemed to imply my copying the files I need manually into the Eclipse Project, but I think this would not work, as when I save those file and later try to load them in the app, they would not actually be the same classes/objects as the ones defined in my Android Studio project, would they?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make your game in Unity? Seems like the obvious choice. You can make games for android, iOS and whatnot. You can test them out easily on your device with the UnityRemote app.

It also supports Java, so you can just copy + paste your already existing code.

Here are some links:

https://unity3d.com

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/2d-game-creation

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like the feel of having made my own framework (with the update-draw-game state basis inspired by James Cho's "Beginner's guide to Android game development but since heavily modified). I have a first game out, called [Brood](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saffronstreams.touou). I made my own Button classes to tweak behavior, but also made a ScreenHelper class to cope with different screen resolutions and aspect ratios. 

I might be "reinventing the wheel" a bit, but it feels like that's part of the fun, and I'm learning things I wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: Seeing how the costs are smaller than I mistakenly remembered (not 15% royalty of gross but actually free while you make less than $100k, and subscription model, not royalties if you surpass 100k), I am starting to get interested more. I'll look into it in more detail these coming days anyway.

Comment: Yeah, Unity is excelent. It's my main developing tool. And they have a lot of amazing features planned for this year. But, of course, it's your choice. You might be "reinventing the wheel" in Android Studio, but as long as you're having fun doing it, it's worth it. I was just trying to find a good solution for your question. Congrats for your Brood game, btw. Looks great! Gonna try it as well.